# why does grid behave like this in a small screen size?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

The code for grid is

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    margin:1% 1% 1% 1%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(75, 75, 74);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgb(41, 40, 40);
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);  

}
```

After a screen size of about 370 x 676 the grid becomes too small in width and is aligned to the left .
[The image is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9ghi.png) .

The grid when screen is bigger is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGfnu.png)

why does the grid behave like this ?

edit: full code for more explanation. The container class is a grid of one column which I wanted to have a big card like appearance . After testing it for smaller screen size the grid seems to add a lot of margin to the right side .

Error occurs even when media query is present . ( commented in code )

```css
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu' , sans-serif;
    background-color: rgb(92, 87, 87);
    color: white;
    background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(33deg ,rgb(247, 204, 36) 0% 7%, rgb(233, 192, 30) 7%  9%);

    }

.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));
    margin:1% 1% 1% 1%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(75, 75, 74);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgb(41, 40, 40);
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);  

}

.nav-wrapper {
    display: flex;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: 1%;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.nav-left {
    display: flex;    
}


.nav-link{
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 40px;
    

}

.nav-left a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

.portfolio-main-card {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    border:2px solid yellow;
    background-color: rgb(134, 107, 134);
    width: 100%;
    height: 50vh;
    
   
}

.my-image {
    flex:1;
    height: 100%;
}
.my-image img{
    height:100%;
    object-fit:contain;
    width: 100%;
}

.my-text {
    display: flex;
    flex:1;
    justify-content: center;
}

.my-text-p{
    font-size: 0.9em;
    font-weight: 600;

}

.portfolio-cards-wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(300px, 1fr));    
    grid-auto-rows: auto;
    margin: 30px 30px 60px 30px;
}

.card {
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding:0.5rem;
    background-color: rgb(66, 62, 62);
    color: #feda6a;
    box-shadow:0px 0px 16px  rgb(0, 0, 0)  ;
    margin:20px 20px 10px 20px;

}

.projects {
    margin: 20px;
}

.projects > p {
    text-align: center;  
    font-weight: 600;  
}

/* @media(max-width : 600px) {
    .container {
        background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }

    .portfolio-main-card {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: red;
    }

    .portfolio-cards-wrapper {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    }


}  */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Condensed&family=Ubuntu:wght@300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">        <link rel="stylesheet" href="decorate.css">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello world</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            
            <div class="nav-wrapper">
                    <div class="nav-left">
                            <li class="nav-link"><a  href="#">education</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-link"><a  href="#">work</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-link"><a  href="#">certificates</a></li>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div class="nav-right">
                            <p>name</p>
                    </div>
            </div>

            <div class="portfolio-main-card">
                        <div class="my-image">
                            <img src="https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fhyperallergic.com%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2016%2F01%2FCat_023-FF.jpg&f=1&nofb=1" alt=""/>

                        </div>
                        <div class="my-text">
                            <div class="my-text-p">
                                <p>Welcome to my portfolio</p>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
            </div>
                    
            <div class="projects">
                <p>PROJECTS</p>
            </div>
            <div class="portfolio-cards-wrapper">
                    <div class="card">
                        <h4>machine learning</h4>
                        <p class="card-details">looking for details</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <h4>computer vision</h4>
                        <p class="card-details">wow</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <h4>python</h4>
                        <p class="card-details">My python projects are as follows</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <h4>final year project</h4>
                        <p class="card-details">My final year project</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> 

            
                    
        </div>       

    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

because you need to add media queries to explicitly tell to your grid how to behave on small screen size

Comment: I added media queries for size lesser than 600px . It works fine till 400px or something and after that it behaves like shown in the explanation .

Comment: add another one for sizes smaller than 400px but in this case you will have to redesign your components in such a way that they will fit. And by the way, who is gonna use your app on 400px-screens and smaller? i think you can leave it as it is

Answer (score 0):

Try adding *grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr));* to .container in css.
I got following results:

```
.container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(500px, 1fr)); 
    margin:1% 1% 1% 1%;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: rgb(75, 75, 74);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 2px rgb(41, 40, 40);
    border: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 0);  

}
```

With this html Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Portfolio</h1>
<h2>Home</h2>
<h3>About</h3>
<div class="containter">
<img src= "ente.jpg" style="width:400px;" >
</div>
<div class="container">

<div style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 0)";><p>My Python Projects</p></div>
<div style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 0)";><p>My HTML Project</p></div>
<div style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 0)";><p>My Winter Project</p></div>
<div style="border: 2px solid rgb(0, 255, 0)";><p>Thats me! </p></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

..
the containers will do an horizontal break if the size of divs fall above 500px when minimize screen size.

The result in desktop view is:

[DesktopView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/duX9F.jpg)

and in Responsive View:

[ResponsiveView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L72gi.jpg)

Comment: This doesn't solve the issue . The grid I used for small cards like design works fine . The container though doesn't work the way I expect it to .